# (3504) error trying to generate a sum in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to modify a query for generating a forecast of future work to summarize the amount of work allocated to certain trades, however I keep getting a 3504 error when I add in the SUM() function. I'm not sure what i'm missing however?

EDITS: included group by and select, not sure why they didnt copy over in the first place...

Notes: Column type for WS.ActivityEstimatedHours is Decimal

```
SELECT
        WO.WorkOrderCodeBK AS "WORKORDER",
        WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK AS "PM",
        WO.WorkOrderDescription AS "DESCRIPTION",
        NULL AS "COMMENTS",
        WO.WorkOrderPlannerNotes AS "PLANNER_COMMENTS",
        WO.WorkOrderStatus AS "STATUS",
        WO.EquipmentOperationsGroup AS "OPSGROUP",
        WO.WorkOrderSurfaceAssetBK AS "DEPARTMENT",
        WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK AS "EQUIPMENT",
        WO.WorkOrderAssignedToResourceBK AS "ASSIGNED_TO",
        CAST( 
            CAST(WO.WorkOrderPMDueDate AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                                                         AS "PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE",
        SE.EquipmentIC AS "EQUIPMENT_IC",
        WO.WorkOrderDeferralExpirationDate AS "DEFERRAL_EXPERATION_DATE",
        WO.WorkOrderObjCriticality AS "CRITICALITY",
        PM.PMWorkOrderJobType AS "PM_TYPE",
        NULL AS "DEFERRAL_REQUIRED_IF_LATE",
        SE.EquipmentCostCode AS "COST_CODE",
        SE.EquipmentClassBK AS "EQ_CLASS",
        WS.ActivityCode AS "Activity",
        WS.ActivityTradeCodeBK AS "Trade",
        SUM(WS.ActivityEstimatedHours) "HOURS"

FROM     IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.DIMWorkOrder WO 
    JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.DIMSurfacePM PM ON PM.PMCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK
    JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.DIMSurfaceEquipment SE ON SE.EquipmentCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK
    LEFT JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.FACTWorkOrderActivity WS ON WS.ActivityWorkOrderCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderCodeBK
WHERE 1=1
AND  DEPARTMENT IN ('CO','CY','KR','LH','MS','SA')
AND  STATUS IN ('R','SCH')
AND  PM IS NOT NULL
AND  PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
AND  PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE <= CURRENT_DATE + 115
AND  WORKORDER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY WORKORDER, PM , DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, PLANNER_COMMENTS, STATUS, OPSGROUP, DEPARTMENT, EQUIPMENT, ASSIGNED_TO, PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE, EQUIPMENT_IC, DEFERRAL_EXPERATION_DATE, CRITICALITY, PM_TYPE, DEFERRAL_REQUIRED_IF_LATE, COST_CODE, EQ_CLASS, Activity, Trade, HOURS
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: Column ActivityEstimatedHours data type?

Comment: @Parfait, Teradata doesn't need any GROUP BY! (Has implicit GROUP BY.)

Comment: I included the base group by I was using, and added the data type for Estimated Hours in the body of the post

Comment: @Parfait, google... No, it's not like that horrible MySQL behavior. AFAIK, columns not arguments to set functions are included in the implicit GROUP BY. (But I can be wrong here...)

Comment: @Cri, what is the error message associated with 3054 for those of us without Teradata?

Comment: @Parfait, the error is as follows : SELECT Failed. 3504: (-3504)Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are using column aliases in `GROUP BY`. In most database engine order of operations for aggregte queries, `GROUP BY` usually precedes `SELECT` so column aliases will not be known on that step. With that said, `ORDER` follows *after* `SELECT`, so can use the `"DEPARTMENT"` alias.

The well-known irony of SQL is that `SELECT` which appears as first clause is usually one of the last steps to be run. Being declarative in nature, SQL is not like procedural languages that run in the order it is written. Therefore, simply use original non-scalar columns in `GROUP BY` and not column aliases.

```
SELECT
        WO.WorkOrderCodeBK AS "WORKORDER",
        WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK AS "PM",
        WO.WorkOrderDescription AS "DESCRIPTION",
        NULL AS "COMMENTS",
        WO.WorkOrderPlannerNotes AS "PLANNER_COMMENTS",
        WO.WorkOrderStatus AS "STATUS",
        WO.EquipmentOperationsGroup AS "OPSGROUP",
        WO.WorkOrderSurfaceAssetBK AS "DEPARTMENT",
        WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK AS "EQUIPMENT",
        WO.WorkOrderAssignedToResourceBK AS "ASSIGNED_TO",
        CAST(CAST(WO.WorkOrderPMDueDate AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')  
             AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE",
        SE.EquipmentIC AS "EQUIPMENT_IC",
        WO.WorkOrderDeferralExpirationDate AS "DEFERRAL_EXPERATION_DATE",
        WO.WorkOrderObjCriticality AS "CRITICALITY",
        PM.PMWorkOrderJobType AS "PM_TYPE",
        NULL AS "DEFERRAL_REQUIRED_IF_LATE",
        SE.EquipmentCostCode AS "COST_CODE",
        SE.EquipmentClassBK AS "EQ_CLASS",
        WS.ActivityCode AS "Activity",
        WS.ActivityTradeCodeBK AS "Trade",
        SUM(WS.ActivityEstimatedHours) AS "HOURS"

FROM     IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.DIMWorkOrder WO 
    INNER JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.DIMSurfacePM PM ON PM.PMCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK
    INNER JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.DIMSurfaceEquipment SE ON SE.EquipmentCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK
    LEFT JOIN IDW_PL_SURFACEMAINTENANCE.FACTWorkOrderActivity WS ON WS.ActivityWorkOrderCodeBK = WO.WorkOrderCodeBK
WHERE 1=1
  AND  DEPARTMENT IN ('CO','CY','KR','LH','MS','SA')
  AND  STATUS IN ('R','SCH')
  AND  PM IS NOT NULL
  AND  PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
  AND  PM_ORIGINAL_DUE_DATE <= CURRENT_DATE + 115
  AND  WORKORDER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
        WO.WorkOrderCodeBK,
        WO.WorkOrderPMCodeBK,
        WO.WorkOrderDescription,
        WO.WorkOrderPlannerNotes,
        WO.WorkOrderStatus,
        WO.EquipmentOperationsGroup,
        WO.WorkOrderSurfaceAssetBK,
        WO.WorkOrderEquipmentCodeBK,
        WO.WorkOrderAssignedToResourceBK,
        CAST(CAST(WO.WorkOrderPMDueDate AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
             AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
        SE.EquipmentIC,
        WO.WorkOrderDeferralExpirationDate,
        WO.WorkOrderObjCriticality,
        PM.PMWorkOrderJobType,
        SE.EquipmentCostCode,
        SE.EquipmentClassBK,
        WS.ActivityCode,
        WS.ActivityTradeCodeBK
ORDER BY "DEPARTMENT"
```

On closer look and as Teradata gold badgeholder, @dnoeth, confirms, Teradata may be an exception to using non-aggregated column aliases in `GROUP BY`. However, OP mistakenly uses the calculated aggregate column alias, `"HOURS"` in `GROUP BY` clause which this referencing is not allowed and may even be redundant.

Comment: Well, Teradata allows using aliases in any place (of course, it's non-Standard, but nice to have) or `group by 1,2,3` (like in ORDER BY). The actual problem is probably due to including the `HOURS` alias in the group by.